# Docusign / Salesforce: Sending an envelope from a Salesforce custom object gives an error message 'no contacts on record'

Tags: javascript, salesforce, docusignapi

I want to send an envelope directly from a Salesforce (custom) object without any end user action required other than hitting the button 'Send with DocuSign'.

But on hitting the button 'Send with DocuSign' I get the error: 'there are no contacts on the Salesforce record you are sending from. Add one or more contacts to the record and try again'. 
And I can only go back to Salesforce.

Of course there are no contacts defined on that object in Salesforce. The object is related to account and contacts and there are the contacts stored.

Why isn't it working correctly? Can anyone help me?

More info: when I change the 'var OCO = "Send";' into 'var OCO = "Tag";' it seems to work. I get the DocuSign page using the correct template and all the Salesforce database data is filled out correctly. So that can't be the issue?

The only other thing is that it doesn't seem to change the recipients (list) as defined in the template with the recipients as defined in the 'var CRL'. 
Can that be the cause of the problem?

more info:
var CRL = "Email~{!customobject__c.E_mail__c};LastName~SignerName;Role~Signer 2;Email~me@home.com;LastName~Myname;Role~Signer 1;LoadDefaultContacts~0";

//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********// 
window.location.href="/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!customobject__c.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by:
- Removing the prefilled email addresses from the template
- Not using the var CRCL and RCRM and instead using the var CRL to fill the email addresses
- Defining the roles correctly and
- Replacing the role ‘3rd Party’ with ‘ContractParty’.